# scripting full-screen, curses-style, updating tabular output (a la top) on unixen

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I am looking for some sort of packages / APIs in Linux that can display output in columns similar to how `top` does.

For example, keep cleaning and rewriting the output to a full screen at a given interval (I guess [watch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) probably does this good enough. But I am hoping to have some APIs that wrap on top of it).

Sort by columns easily. Particularly if I sort by column A, then when next time I re-print everything, it remembers to sort by that column A every time the output is refreshed.

And of course, ideally it can handle the keyboard input for me as well.

All in all, I am looking for packages or APIs that can help me organize my output in a way "`top`" organizes it.

Just to clarity: What I display might be completely unrelated to the system statistics. I just like the way top organizes the content. For example, My output content might be (and it's constantly changing, which is why it needs to be cleaned and rewritten):

> Time Col1 Col2
>   12   4     13
>   13   5     19
>   14   5     15

I can hit a key say "A" then it sorts by Time. If I hit a key B then it sorts by Col1. If I hit a key say C then it sorts by Col2, etc, etc.

And of course this output content can be entirely in memory, organized in any data structures.

Comment: Are you looking for [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)?

Comment: ncurses sounds lower level; it doesn't handle the column management, for example.

Comment: Maybe `dialog`?  (http://jaduks.livejournal.com/7508.html) I don't think shell script is the correct tool to build a dynamic user interface...

Comment: @tMC just like why top is still one of the most popular commands in Linux, displaying rich content in shell can still be very convenient. :)

Comment: @chrisaycock It almost has everything I want except that column handling part. and I still have to specify where to print what strings. That's a bit annoying.

Comment: I'll really be surprised if someone can post a bash-centric solution to this (but will of course happily up-vote it). You're not looking to replace top are you? It would help if you edited your question to include sample input and required outputs. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Added Python tag. hopefully that will have richer libraries.

Comment: just for clarity, you're interested in technical details of the implementation to display and not primarily how to acquire the displayed system statistics?

Comment: @CodeNoob, but `top` is not written in shell script

Comment: @moooeeeep yes, what I display might be completely not related to system statistics.

Comment: As for columns, you could pipe to `column -t` (assuming you don't have spaces). My system has it at least. No idea how portable that is.

Comment: the [source code (mtop)](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/gwydion/hackers/nkramer/mindy/1.5/mindy-1.5/doc/mindy/converters/miftran/mtop.c) is a good read (if you like C).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the curses library in Python handy for this sort of requirement. It still doesn't support column management, but it provides a decent solution with a sane language, a nice document and a manageable learning curve.

If anyone else has better suggestion, I would be happy to pick his as the best answer.

http://docs.python.org/howto/curses.html

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do this in shell, watch + printf would be a quick and dirty place to start -- watch to rerun a script every few seconds, printf to do the formatting, roughly as so:

```
printf '%-20s %-20s\n' \
  header1 header2 \
  line1data1 line1data2 \
  line2data1 line2data2 ...
```

...with the data presumably being constructed in and fed from an array. Simply looping within your script and emitting the appropriate control codes to clear each line as you're about to overwrite it (and moving to the top of the window at the beginning) is another reasonable approach.

That said, the right tool here will be a layer built on top of curses. There are a number of higher-level textual widget sets out there already -- but I don't know of anything with direct support for tables.

If you were willing to write C, one such wrapper around curses is [GAP.Browse](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/browse.html).

Comment: If you run 'clear' before the printf, you can automatically get the screen to clear and have the cursor position reset to 0,0 as well - further mimicing 'top' behavior.

Comment: probably sed/awk can convert any input into a table.

Comment: @moooeeeep they can, but why use subprocesses for something your language can do internally?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy as I understood, this question is more about bash scripting than C/C++

Comment: @moooeeeep yes, I agree. printf is something bash can do internally (if you run `type printf` the response is `printf is a shell builtin`).

Answer (score 0):

There's [CDK](http://invisible-island.net/cdk/). I tried it, and it's all right, feels a bit like GTK. But a `printf` solution is far cleaner.

If you don't mind scripting languages, you could try [rbcurse](https://github.com/rkumar/rbcurse), which has more features. It has very bad documentation though.